# Python library deployment

Tags: python, deployment, virtualenv, anaconda

I have created a python library using sklearn and some other dependencies. I want other developers to be able to use it in their programs, in a non-public environment(e.g.within a organization) They will use this library for to write their own applications.
Some questions that I have are -

> - What is a best way to make it available to other developers?
> - Let's say , the developers have their own python installation, and they use a version 1.x of a package(e.g. sklearn etc) but my
>     package uses 2.x, will there be a problem? If yes, how can i ensure they
>     can use my library.
> - I want to make my library available for both Python 2.7 and 3.x users. Do I need two different deployments? Currently my library
>     works(no version specific calls for 2.7/3.x) in both 2.7 and 3.x, if
>     the correct dependencies are pre-installed by the user.

Comment: Try looking up `distutils` or `setuptools`.

Answer (score 0):

1. The best way is to publish at [PyPI](https://pypi.python.org/pypi). That way your user have ti just run `pip install $LIB` and got it with all dependencies (if you properly configured dependencies). See [Python Packaging User Guide](https://packaging.python.org/).
2. Just recommend your users to use virtualenv. Virtual environments are the way to separate and install different versions of Python libraries and programs to coexist at one system.
3. Very much depends on the nature of your library. There are libraries that can be installed to both Python 2 and 3 from one source and there are libraries that require different package for every python version.